# XQuery - Error - XML-20201

Tags: xml, runtime-error, xquery, sax, saxon

I am trying to run an XQuery file using Saxon. I keep getting this error when the code execute. The funny thing is the XQ works fine when i debug it as a standalone file in XMLSpy. When i deploy it and run my application, it throws the following exception:

```
Error reading datasource: XQuery Processor Exception: Exception while calling Saxon: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: : XML-20201: (Fatal Error) Expected name instead of :.; SystemID: ; Line#: 8; Column#: -1; Cause: : XML-20201: (Fatal Error) Expected name instead of :.
```

I am not able to figure out where the error happens and what i can do to fix it. My only guess is the the input XMLs to XQuery might be an issue. But i am not sure which line in the XQuery is failing. As line 8 is commented line!

Is there any way to narrow it down, where the error is coming from?

Comment: Does the XQuery load any XML documents? The SAXParseException suggests parsing an XML document is failing. How do you use Saxon, from the command line or within your Java code? If you use Java code make sure you use a namespace aware SAXParserFactory: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory.html#setNamespaceAware(boolean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What API are you using for running the query, and how do you load the source document?

It looks as if an error is being reported to Saxon by the XML parser for the source document. The line #8 is a reference to a line number in the source document. From the form of the parser exception, I would suspect that you are using a pull parser, perhaps via the XQJ API. (But you've told us so little that this is pure speculation.)

First check that the XML source document is actually well-formed. If it is, then this could be a problem with the pull parser: some of the StAX parsers I have tested with have been very unreliable, and the only one I can recommend is Woodstox.

Comment: @MartinHonnen @ MichaelKay 
Sorry for the delay, I was able to figure out what was wrong. It was a way the eclipse was saving the XML. I did Ctrl+I to indent the XML. So some of the lines wrapped and went to the next line. When the xml got loaded the the tag name and the "xmlns" had no space in between them. So it was throwing an exception.
Thanks for the tips, i was able to pick up clues from what you guys said. Thanks!